# Cloning git branch in pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

Based on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-git-integration.html, I can clone a repository. However by default it clones the master branch. How can I clone any other branch? I tried http://xxx.git -b name_of_branch, but pycharm does not seem to like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It clones full repository. You need to fetch/pull https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html
 and switch to another branch (look for "Manage branches" in that text).